# Getting an HTML page upon requesting json api

Tags: java, json, api

I am making request to an api which sends back response as json data. But sometimes it sends back an html page which has api documentation. In documentation it's nowhere mentioned that the api can send a different response that json. There is no pattern as to when it sends json and when Html page. Sometimes same request sends back HTML and other times json response. I want to know what could be possible reasons of this exception. Is it problem with APi or my code.

I am using below code to fetch the response

```
URI uri = new URI(url);
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uri.toURL().openStream())); 
            while ((line = b.readLine()) != null)
            {
            s.append(line); 
            }
tokener = new JSONTokener(s.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

It is probably because of the Accept header in the HTTP request not being set. Try the following:

```
URI uri = new URI(url);
URLConnection httpCon = uri.toURL().openConnection();
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream())); 
while ((line = b.readLine()) != null)
{
      s.append(line); 
}
tokener = new JSONTokener(s.toString());
```

Comment: It says "Cannot instantiate the type HttpURLConnection". I have imported java.net.HttpURLConnection

Comment: Yeah,the code is error free now. I will test it and update.